# Better way to store operator and comparison value

Tags: php, mysql

I need to store the operator and their value into the database because after, in a loop, I have to make the comparison for a price calc.

These values come from an HTML form that asks few question, ie:

Question: How many items?
Answer: `<`  *(select options)* `10` *(textbox)*

Question: When?
Answer: `=`  *(select options)* `2013-12-13` *(textbox)*

What is the best way to store these two values into a table field with multiple questions?
Serialize with PHP operator and value?
Store a string `< 10` or `= 2013-12-13`?

Please let me know if you know a better tecnique.

My MySQL table is

```js
CREATE TABLE answers(
    id         INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    answer_1     VARCHAR(50),
    answer_2     VARCHAR(50),
    answer_3     VARCHAR(50),
    ...
);
```

**UPDATE**
I've missed an important part of the post, I've update the question: my table as multiple answers fields.

Comment: two fields. `operator` and `value`. don't try and smash them into a single field.

Comment: Sorry guys, I've missed an important part of the post (now updated), my table as multiple answers fields, and I can't add operator and value field for each answer. Hope I've cleared my question.

Comment: The way you store your data is important not only when you add it to your DB but also when and how you use it. It is also very important what kind of data you will add to it. My gut reaction is to suggest storing them as a comma-separated string so that you can use PHP's `explode` and `implode` to process the data... but that will not work if either of the values can have a comma in them. If not, you need to sanitize the data to make sure it doesn't as well.

Comment: Thanks @Toote you have confirmed my solution. The form is not so flexible - different fields, type of data, no references to question or answers - and as far as I know this is a good compromise to store this kind of data.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the design of the mysql database goes against good DBMS design principles.

If you have known questions in a form, you don't put the answers to ALL the questions into a generic answer field.

You definitely want to store the "less than/equal to/etc" operator in a discrete field, but you also want to store dates in a date field. and item quantities in an appropriate integer/numeric.

Based on your question, I don't have enough information to know whether you need more complex data structures (i.e. a Questions table, etc) but based on the information you gave you would want something more like:

```
CREATE TABLE answers(
    id         INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    modItems    VARCHAR(4), // the greaterthan/lessthan for numItems
    numItems    INTEGER,
    modDate     VARCHAR(4), // the greaterthan/lessthan for dateDelivery,
    dateDelivery DATETIME   );
```

Also, looking at your use case, you may want to alter the structure of the web form that generates the data. Is a user really going to say they want "less than 10 items"? I assume they are going to know (or estimate) how many items they want. If you're going to end up giving them special processing/deals/etc based on the number of items, just let them choose the item range you will end up using anyway, i.e. an option list populated with 1-9 items/10-50 items/ 51-100 items etc.

Comment: You are right in a good DBMS design your answer is a good way to go, but the form is not so flexible - different fields, type of data - and I'm just trying to find a better compromise to store data as better as possible. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Keep them separate - your table would look/work better if it was more like this:

```
CREATE TABLE answers(
    `id`         INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `answer_id`  INTEGER,
    `operator`   TEXT,
    `value`      TEXT,
    UNIQUE KEY `answer` (`id`,`answer_id`)
);
```

(Use NOT NULL/correct column types as appropriate for your situation, of course)

`answer_id` must be determined programmatically before inserting the data, but you do that already for the column names `answer_1`/etc.